# Horizontal and collapsible navbar with only CSS3

Tags: html, css, nav

I want to get horizontal navbar menu that for mobile phone (say less than 600px of width of screen) I get [collapsible baricon menu](http://fontawesome.io/icon/bars/). In other words, the same result as [Brian Buccola](http://brianbuccola.com/ben-carson-any-and-context/) site but **only** with CSS3.

[image]

Let's start with this:

```
<header>
<nav id="site-navigation" class="site-navigation">
  <ul>
   <li><a class="page-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
   <li><a class="page-link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
   <li><a class="page-link" href="work.html">Work</a></li>
   <li><a class="page-link" href="cv.html">CV</a></li>
   <li><a class="page-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: The only reason this is not working is because no attempt has been made at adding required `CSS`. In it's current form it is an *"I need this done for free, thank you"* type of question. It does not include any research effort or coding attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrei: I can't add comments since I recently joined the community. What I meant is that to have it work on click you would have to use javascript to add a click event. (I think the original question mentioned a click)

**I've edited my answer** to make it more clear:

As Paul mentioned you can't entirely replicate a click event with CSS. However I had a look at the link that you provided and it seems like the navigation is shown on `hover` rather than click. I tried to write something to replicate what he is doing there:

```
<header>
  <nav id="site-navigation" class="site-navigation">
    <a href="#" class="menu-icon">Mobile menu</a> <!-- replace with icon -->
    <ul class="site-navigation-items">
     <li><a class="page-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a class="page-link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

The CSS would look something like this:

```
.site-navigation {
    text-align: right;
}
.site-navigation-items {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.site-navigation-items li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}
@media(max-width: 600px) {
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
  .site-navigation-items {
    display: none;
  }
  .site-navigation-items li {
    display: block;
  }
  .site-navigation:hover .site-navigation-items {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I personally would use a bit of javascript and add an onClick event to the icon, but if you want to use only CSS that is how you could achieve something similar. (it's not the prettiest approach tho).

Good luck!

Comment: First, welcome to [so]. Regarding your edit: toggling menus open/closed with CSS alone is totally possible using a non-rendered `checkbox` and styling the dropdown open state with `input:checked + .dropdown {}` - using the dropdown toggle as input label, of course. When you also want to add touch events to it, maybe animations, maybe close on tap/click outside of it, while it's still possible without `JS`, it becomes less elegant and bloated in `CSS`, whereas `JS` syntax is shorter, simpler and more expressive. However, stating it's not possible without `JS` is simply not true.

Answer (score 1):

The menu on the website you have provided as example does exactly what you ask for. It doesn't use any `JavaScript`. Therefore, a simple copy/paste of their code will do:

```css
body { font: 400 16px/1.5 "PT Sans", sans-serif; color: #111; background-color: #fdfdfd; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1; -moz-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1; -o-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1; font-feature-settings: "kern" 1; font-kerning: normal; }
.site-nav { float: right; line-height: 56px; }
.site-nav .menu-icon { display: none; }
.site-nav .page-link { color: #939598; line-height: 1.5; }
.site-nav .page-link:not(:last-child) { margin-right: 20px; }
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { .site-nav { position: absolute; top: 9px; right: 15px; background-color: #fdfdfd; border: 1px solid #fbfbfc; border-radius: 5px; text-align: right; }
  .site-nav .menu-icon { display: block; float: right; width: 36px; height: 26px; line-height: 0; padding-top: 10px; text-align: center; }
  .site-nav .menu-icon > svg { width: 18px; height: 15px; }
  .site-nav .menu-icon > svg path { fill: #545558; }
  .site-nav .trigger { clear: both; display: none; }
  .site-nav:hover .trigger { display: block; padding-bottom: 5px; }
  .site-nav .page-link { display: block; padding: 5px 10px; margin-left: 20px; }
  .site-nav .page-link:not(:last-child) { margin-right: 0; } }
  
.site-nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.site-nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
  <a href="#" class="menu-icon">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 18 15">
      <path fill="#424242" d="M18,1.484c0,0.82-0.665,1.484-1.484,1.484H1.484C0.665,2.969,0,2.304,0,1.484l0,0C0,0.665,0.665,0,1.484,0 h15.031C17.335,0,18,0.665,18,1.484L18,1.484z"></path>
      <path fill="#424242" d="M18,7.516C18,8.335,17.335,9,16.516,9H1.484C0.665,9,0,8.335,0,7.516l0,0c0-0.82,0.665-1.484,1.484-1.484 h15.031C17.335,6.031,18,6.696,18,7.516L18,7.516z"></path>
      <path fill="#424242" d="M18,13.516C18,14.335,17.335,15,16.516,15H1.484C0.665,15,0,14.335,0,13.516l0,0 c0-0.82,0.665-1.484,1.484-1.484h15.031C17.335,12.031,18,12.696,18,13.516L18,13.516z"></path>
    </svg>
  </a>

  <div class="trigger">
    <a class="page-link" href="/">Home</a>
    <a class="page-link" href="/about/">About</a>
    <a class="page-link" href="/work/">Work</a>
    <a class="page-link" href="/cv/">CV</a>
    <a class="page-link" href="/blog/">Blog</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Note:** I haven't authored any of the code above, it's taken entirely from your example. If I was to code a similar menu, I'd code it differently. However, I'm not going to put in the effort for it before your question shows signs of proper research and at least one coding attempt.

---

Apart from your inability or unwillingness to properly research the task before asking on StackOverflow, what I really find mind blowing is that now you have two answers stating it cannot be done without `JavaScript`, but the very example you provided does it without any!

Comment: Yeah it's the code of the page I provided but it uses `div` instead of `nav`: the links of the menu are not part of the list, they are part of a div. I want to fit to recommended standards.

Comment: @somenxavier What exactly is using `<div>` instead of `<nav>`? Which particular `<div>` should be `<nav>` in your opinion?

Comment: In my opinion `<div class="trigger">` must disappear and links must be in `nav`.

Comment: That would mean you have a `<nav>` inside another `<nav>`. [`Current standard`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-nav-element) doesn't specify they can't be nested, but I think it could get confusing to index/search engines. I don't consider nesting `<nav>`  tags a good practice. But nobody's stopping you from nesting them. Besides, the code above will work regardless of the used tag.

Comment: No. I mean using `<div>` instead of  `<nav>`

Comment: @somenxavier I can totally understand why you mark an answer which tells you it cannot be done with `JavaScript` as correct, when you asked for it to be done without `JavaScript`, over an answer which tells you: *"hey, mate, what you linked does it without any `JavaScript`. Here's the extracted code!*". It just makes so much sense.

Comment: The solution makes no use of javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that fontawesome site example in CSS3 only because you'll need an onclick event listener to bring up the menu items in a different style for a smaller screen size.

A simple example of a responsive menu with minimal javascript is here:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

Hope this helps.

Paul.

Comment: Actually Paul, you could do that just with css. Like this for example:https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/9qzf14yh/

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please note collapsible menus with pure `CSS` are not only entirely possible, but have been popular for more than 10 years. A simple search will provide good examples. Same goes for @Ninjabin's answer.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the font-awesome site he gave as an example, which has an onclick drop down menu.  I've amended my answer accordingly.